# Measurable random variables constant on generators of sigma algebra?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $_1, … , _$ be a partition of $$ with $ℙ[_] > 0$ for all $$, and
let $G ≔ (_1, … , _)$. Now if  is a random variable that is $G$-measurable it means I thing that the preimage of each borel set is in $G$ right? But why is the random variable $X$ constant on each $E_1,...,E_n$? If I suppose that on for instance that on $E_j$ X takes two values $a$ and $b$ the I know $X^{-1}(a)$ and $X^{-1}(b)$ must be in $G ≔ (_1, … , _)$ but how to continue?

**Edit**

I think I get it now. Consider $E_j$ and let $\omega\in E_j$. Then say $X(\omega)=a$. Now $X^{-1}(a)\cap E_j$ is a non-empty measurable subset of  $E_j$ But. Since $E_j$ is the only non-empty measurable subset of $E_j$ then $X^{-1}(a)\cap E_j=E_j$ meaning $X|_{E_j}=a$

Answer (score 1):

To make thing more clear, let $\mathcal G=\sigma (E_1,E_2)=\{X,E_1, E_2,\varnothing \}.$

As you can see if there are $$X(\omega _1)=:a\neq b:=X(\omega _2),$$ where $\omega _1,\omega _2\in E_1$, then $X^{-1}(a)\subsetneq E_1$, and thus $X$ is not measurable.